# Add new object with facebook developer api v2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to add new object through Object Browser.

I have 2 apps with facebook integration, they both api versions are 2.8,
in one of them everything works perfect, In the second one I cant add new objects.

Before facebook disabled Custom Open Graph and updated the api to 2.8 I had no problems....

**First App:** have the "New Object" button

[The App with the option to add objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQQIm.png)

**Second App:** doesnt have the "New Object" button

[The App that has no "add" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr4iT.png)

I've double checked all setting in both apps to see that I didn't forgot something and its all seems OK.

If there is any other option to add new object (not throuth the Object Browser) it will be great to. I've tried to add  through  Graph API Explorer with no success.

Thanks in advance

Moti Monsonego

Comment: If your second app was created after API v2.8 was released, then you can not create custom OG objects any more in it. And for all other apps they will be removed soon as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any alternative for adding objects? I need to implement energy system that works with "AskFor" and "Send".

Comment: You can only use the default objects and actions.

Comment: Thanks again @CBroe , I'm not familiar with the default objects and action, do you have any guide that I can help with?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph has all the built-in actions and objects provided by Facebook.

Comment: I have the same question. The link only shows the build-in object types, how to get the object ID of the specific type (e.g. games.play) ?

Answer (score 1):

As Facebook announced

> Custom Open Graph stories are deprecated in Graph API 2.8. Graph API 2.7 and lower will support custom Open Graph stories according to the following schedule:
>
> Support for creating new objects will end in January 2017. Support for
>   publishing existing objects will end October 2017.

Now we can only use predefined [Object Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#object-type) and [Action Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#action-type)

Objects instance are defined by [Open Graph HTML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) markup on web pages. If you don't have a web server to host your content, you can use the [Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api/) to upload and publish objects.

To get New Object Button in [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser)
You have to first register object type

1. Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Get App Access Token
3. Change method To *POST* from drop down
4. Press *Add a Field*
5. write in Name Field *object*
6. In Value Field Add your object's JSON e.g

```
    {
      "app_id":APP_ID,
      "type":"product",
      "url":"http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/306382486524859",
      "title":"SAMPLE TITLE",
      "image":"URL OF YOU IMAGE",
      "description":"SAMPLE DESCRIPTION"
    }
```

```
 - app_id – This is the ID of your game.
 - type – type of Object you arecreating. 
 - url – This should be the url of your game. 
 - title – The title to display. 
 - image – The url to the image that you want to display. 
 - description – A short description of the object.
```

[Graph API Explorer Screenshot for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQEky.jpg)

7. Press Submit
8. If everything is correct, you should see an ID returned as a response.
9. Now Go To [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser)
10. There will be a New Object Button

Comment: as indicated in screenshot you should post to /app/objects/{object_type} in this example : product.


list of object types can be found here(under Object Types) :

 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph