# Can I send life to a friend using facebook-unity sdk on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to implement "ask life", "send life" features in my game. Now I'm stuck with facebook-unity sdk. I was able to send simple requests with FB.AppRequest, but can't figure how to send requests with OGActionType.SEND and OGActionType.ASKFOR types. As I figured out, I need to send *objectId* of the object that i want send to another player. But, I can't figure out how to add it. Object browser in facebook developer dashboard doesn't contains button for adding new object [image: Object browser]

I found another question, where mentioned that 2.8 FB api doesn't support creation of new objects: [Add new object with facebook developer api v2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724253/add-new-object-with-facebook-developer-api-v2-8)

So, I have 2 main questions currently:

1. Is it possible to implement "send life" feature with facebook-unity api ?
2. If yes, can I do something to add facebook OG object or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want, and I believe OG objects are the way to do it. I wrote a tutorial a while back on how to achieve just this, since it took me a while too to figure it out.

Hope it helps you!

http://www.bigfootgaming.net/blog/tutorials/facebook-open-graph-objects-in-unity3d/